# How can I populate a list in a MongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb, list, append, document, populate

I want to populate within a loop a MongoDB document's list, without overwriting the existing entries of the list. Something like python's append. Is there a command that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$Push](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/push/) operator.
If you need advance check Modifiers also.